# On call schedule rotation nagios 4

Tags: nagios

I have a monitoring platform installed under a RHEL 6.5 OS in a virtual machine (VMWare EsXi 5.1) consisting of nagios 4.0.7, mrtg 2.17.4 and cacti 0.8.8b. I was upgrading my contacts.cfg file and my timeperiods.cfg file in order to make the on call rotations automatic and I still find it manual in the way that you can't have a calendar in which nagios takes a look to update the timeperiods and contacts right away.

I was wondering if anybody knows a plugin or a way to make a link between a calendar and nagios so that nagios is updated by modifying the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at noma: http://www.netways.de/en/de/produkte/monitoring_add_ons/noma/.  Another option is pagerduty http://www.pagerduty.com/.  It will handle the rotations and schedules for you.  That is what we are using.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios 3 here but what we do is have dedicated on-call Nagios contacts (one for SMS and one for mail) and use custom `service_notification_commands`/`host_notification_commands` scripts which pull the contact information (phone number, email address) from our custom on-call rotation backend.

Another possibility would be to generate config files, one for each on-call contact, and have a symlink to the currently active one and have Nagios only include the symlink'd config file in addition to a cron job rotating the symlink based on your calendar. Or skip the symlinking and just have the cron job generate the on-call config file on the fly, whichever seems easier, more elegant and robust.

Comment: That would definitely be how I'd do it, too; since NAGIOS allows arbitrary executables to be invoked to do notification, build the logic into them.